# In spring-boot Class constructor get called first or bootstrap.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I Have a spring-boot application. I wanted to pick some values from `bootstrap.yml` into the constructor of the class. Below is the code Snippet.

```
public class MapicsSCFFGeneratorServiceImpl implements MapicsSCFFGeneratorService {

    @Value("${azuresb.nameSpace}")
    private String nameSpace;

    @Value("${azuresb.sasPolicyKeyName}")
    private String sasPolicyKeyName;

    @Value("${azuresb.sasPolicyKey}")
    private String sasPolicyKey;

    @Value("${azuresb.serviceBusRootURI}")
    private String serviceBusRootURI;

    @Value("${azuresb.queueName}")
    private String queueName;

    public MapicsSCFFGeneratorServiceImpl() {

        config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(nameSpace, sasPolicyKeyName, sasPolicyKey,
                serviceBusRootURI);

    }
}
```

My question is Which one get call first **bootstrap.yml** or **constructor**

Because If I am printing this values inside constructor I am getting Null on the other hand outsides the constructor the values are printing.

Comment: An instance must be created before setting the fields, so yes the constructor is called first.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense that the constructor be invoked before the Spring processing that values the fields with Spring properties.  
From a logical point of view, the constructor has to be invoked before Spring values instance fields.

As alternative, you could move the processing that uses the fields valued by Spring in a method annotated with `javax.annotation.@PostConstruct`.

From the specification :

> The `PostConstruct` annotation is used on a method that needs to be
>   executed after dependency injection is done to perform any
>   initialization.

```
@PostConstruct
public void postProcess(){
   config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(nameSpace, sasPolicyKeyName, sasPolicyKey,
                serviceBusRootURI);
}
```